# Add gestures to all views using a custom framework

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I am writing a framework using swift that should add a gesture recogniser to all views wherever that is being added.

So in my sample.framework i did something like this-

```
import UIKit

public class SampleSDK: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    sharedInitialization()
}


required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    sharedInitialization()
}

func sharedInitialization() {
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SampleSDK.tapGesture(_:)))
    gesture.delegate = self
    self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func tapGesture(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("tap working")
}

}
```

Now i want to add this framework to an existing app and want that all views of that app should respond to tap.

When i am adding to any UIViewController

```
self.view = SampleSDK()
```

this works, but i don't want this to add in every View. this need to be pluggable.